# On click previous/next button, I want to highlight the image which is next or prev

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am creating the navigation for this coin
currently it works on click now i want to navigate it also using button(prev button, next button)
I dont want to keep history
when i click previour or next button, i dont want to highlight the image which user had cliked earlier
'I want to highlight the image which is next in navigation
like if img id=02 is highlited then on next button click 03 should be highlited.
How is that possible?

```js
function switchVisible() {
            if (document.getElementById('mapButtons')) {

                if (document.getElementById('mapButtons').style.display == 'none') {
                    document.getElementById('mapButtons').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('modelButtons').style.display = 'none';     
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('mapButtons').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('modelButtons').style.display = 'block';
     
                }
            }
}
function flip() {
    $('.side').toggleClass('rotated');
}

var img_id = 2;

$(function() {
    $('area').mouseover(function() {
        var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
       // $('#demo').text("Mouseover for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('invert',true)
            .css('z-index',2);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
      //  $('#mi').text("Mouseout for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('invert',false)
            .css('z-index',1);
    }).click(function() {
    var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
    //$('#demo').text("click for "+imgid);

    $('.pressed').removeClass('pressed');
   img_id= imgid;
  //  $('#d').text("new function "+img_id);
    $('#'+imgid)
        .toggleClass('pressed')
        .css('z-index',2);
});
});


$(function() {
var img = img_id;
 $('#d').text("new function "+img);
  //var img = 2;
  var min = 2;
  var max = 12;

  $('.prevButton').on('click',function(e) {
    if (img > min) {
       removeAllBorders();
        img--;
        $('#' + img).toggleClass('pressed');
    }
  });

  $('.nextButton').on('click',function(e) {
     if (img < max) {
       removeAllBorders();
       img++;
       $('#' + img).toggleClass('pressed');
     }
  });

  function removeAllBorders() {
     $('img').removeClass('pressed');
  }
});
```

```css
#container img {position: absolute;}

img.invert {
    filter: invert(100%);
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
}
img.pressed {
    filter: invert(100%);
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
}

.side {
 position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.side.rotated {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    transform:rotateY(360deg);
}
.back {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}


#mapButtons { position:absolute;top:90%;}
#modelButtons {
 display: none;
  position:absolute;top:90%;
}
.block {
   width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   -webkit-perspective:100%;
    -moz-perspective:100%;
    -ms-perspective:100%;
    -o-perspective:100%;
    perspective:100%;   
}


#flip-button {
    background: white;
    font-family:'open sans';
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #5b5b5b;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.prevButton img {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.prevButton:hover img {
opacity: .5;
}

.nextButton img {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.nextButton:hover img {
opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<body>
<map name="map" id="id_1">
<div="container">
<div class="front side">
<img src="leftovers_ch01.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9;z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="2" class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/fpqmClk.png" style='z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="3" class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/TfhyWZs.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="4" class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/mUKWK5P.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="5" class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/R1JhAT9.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="6" class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/yMGFR2V.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="7" class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/rpCnGxL.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="8" class="myBorder"  src="http://i.imgur.com/FWRCUs4.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="9"  class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/Aw3NhT9.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="10" class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/gWhUtyJ.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="11"  class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/IIJqsxf.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="12"  class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/a9UW5mj.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
</div>

   <area  data-imgid="12"  shape="poly" coords="173,223,176,222,183,224,185,217,190,199,193,192,198,187,193,176,158,132,126,92,132,93,123,79,101,97,81,123,66,149,57,170,50,194,48,211,136,217,131,225,149,225,149,221,152,221,156,215,158,208,159,197,167,189,170,179,173,177,169,171,190,176,192,187,190,190,182,198"
   />

   <area  data-imgid="11"  shape="poly" coords="173,229,181,229,184,243,192,256,201,265,201,271,179,309,174,302,125,375,106,361,88,342,71,319,59,295,52,270,48,252,47,243,65,240,61,248,147,234,147,236,150,234,150,238,154,234,154,239,156,235,159,246,165,262,175,275,185,284,195,270,184,259,177,249,174,237,173,229"
   />

   <area  data-imgid="10"  id="ch10" coords="208,268,220,272,234,272,249,266,253,272,235,280,223,280,214,279,215,274,202,283208,298,209,295,222,297,239,296,251,293,261,288,259,293,262,290,262,296,264,294,65,298,266,295,276,310,266,309,304,389,285,398,259,404,241,406,210,407,187,402,169,398,152,390,158,373,162,380,203,273,208,268"   
   />

   <area  data-imgid="9"  class="notbutton" id="ch09" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="252,265,255,266,256,271,267,262,275,249,279,233,296,234,291,255,282,270,272,280,268,283,274,284,270,286,274,288,271,290,275,291,272,292,328,359,319,359,331,374,349,360,366,342,381,321,392,299,400,276,404,257,407,240,318,235,323,227,278,227,272,231,269,244,262,256,252,265" 
   />

   <area  data-imgid="8"  class="notbutton" id="ch08" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="251,188,253,181,267,192,273,200,277,208,278,212,274,213,288,220,298,207,294,207,289,196,284,186,274,174,262,166,268,166,266,164,270,162,267,161,270,159,266,158,276,142,279,151,329,78,338,85,349,94,363,108,379,129,391,152,397,168,403,189,406,211,389,213,393,206,277,225,272,222,269,209,262,197,251,188" 
   />

   <area  data-imgid="7" class="notbutton" id="ch07" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="247,186,248,182,251,179,239,175,228,173,216,174,206,177,199,161,213,157,225,156,239,157,254,162,254,158,256,159,257,155,258,157,259,152,260,154,292,72,296,79,302,63,286,56,263,50,242,47,213,47,188,51,166,57,149,64,188,143,179,143,201,181,208,185,218,182,236,182,247,186" 
   />

   <area  data-imgid="6" class="notbutton" id="ch06_09" shape="poly" coords="156,234,156,226,154,222,154,226,150,223,150,226,147,224,148,227,130,227,135,220,47,213,31,223,16,212,15,226,16,236,16,243,33,254,48,243,66,240,61,248,148,233,147,236,151,234,151,237,153,234,154,239,156,234"   
   />

  <area  data-imgid="6"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_08" shape="poly" coords="173,230,173,227,180,224,184,228,180,230,173,230"   
  />   

  <area  data-imgid="6"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_07" shape="poly" coords="205,264,207,268,203,272,162,380,158,372,151,389,154,407,136,417,124,412,115,406,108,401,125,394,125,375,174,302,179,309,200,271,201,266,205,264"   
  />  

  <area  data-imgid="6"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_06" shape="poly" coords="261,288,260,291,263,290,262,295,264,293,264,297,266,295,275,309,266,309,305,389,321,397,319,415,330,412,341,405,347,400,347,379,330,374,318,359,328,359,272,292,274,291,271,289,275,288,269,287,273,284,267,284,261,288"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="6" class="notbutton" id="ch06_05" shape="poly" coords="249,264,249,268,253,273,256,271,254,266,249,264"   
  /> 

  <area  data-imgid="6"  class="notbutton"id="ch06_04" shape="poly" coords="271,227,273,223,277,225,393,206,388,214,407,211,420,200,436,210,438,218,438,229,437,242,422,231,406,240,318,235,323,227,277,227,274,230,271,227"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="6" class="notbutton" id="ch06_03" shape="poly" coords="256,163,262,166,267,165,265,164,269,162,266,161,269,159,266,158,276,142,279,150,329,78,329,59,344,51,333,45,323,39,316,36,300,45,303,63,296,80,292,72,260,154,259,153,259,158,256,155,257,159,254,158,256,163"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="6" class="notbutton" id="ch06_02" shape="poly" coords="248,189,247,183,251,180,253,181,252,186,248,189"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="6" class="notbutton" id="ch06_01" shape="poly" coords="199,191,203,188,207,192,205,187,207,185,202,182,178,142,188,143,149,64,133,55,133,37,122,44,112,49,107,53,107,73,123,78,135,93,126,93,199,183,199,191"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="5" class="notbutton" id="ch05_06" shape="poly" coords="16,212,31,223,47,214,50,189,55,169,62,152,70,136,81,120,92,107,105,93,118,82,123,79,107,73,107,54,91,65,73,83,57,101,45,119,36,137,27,158,20,183,17,202,16,212"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="5" class="notbutton"id="ch05_05" shape="poly" coords="108,401,125,394,125,375,112,366,97,352,83,336,69,316,61,298,54,280,49,261,47,243,33,255,16,244,20,270,27,293,34,313,45,334,57,352,71,369,88,385,108,401"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="5" class="notbutton" id="ch05_04" shape="poly" coords="305,389,321,398,319,415,290,427,265,433,237,436,208,436,181,432,159,426,136,417,154,407,151,391,171,399,192,404,213,407,236,407,261,404,280,399,296,393,305,389"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="5" class="notbutton" id="ch05_03" shape="poly" coords="406,240,423,231,437,242,434,264,429,285,424,302,416,320,404,341,390,360,375,376,357,391,347,399,347,380,331,374,345,363,358,350,370,336,380,323,387,309,395,294,399,279,403,265,406,247,406,240"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="5" class="notbutton"id="ch05_02" shape="poly" coords="329,77,328,58,344,52,363,66,383,85,396,101,410,123,421,144,428,164,433,182,436,199,436,210,420,200,406,211,404,191,398,169,390,149,380,131,365,110,352,97,339,86,329,77"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="5" class="notbutton" id="ch05_01" shape="poly" coords="132,55,134,37,152,30,174,23,200,18,219,17,240,17,260,19,276,22,291,26,303,31,316,36,300,45,303,63,284,55,265,51,250,48,234,46,215,47,194,49,175,53,157,60,149,64,132,55"   
  /> 

   <area  data-imgid="5" class="notbutton" id="ch04_03" shape="poly" coords="195,270,185,284,174,273,166,263,160,251,157,240,156,226,158,211,163,195,174,180,177,177,174,175,191,176,192,191,188,189,178,203,173,219,173,233,177,248,185,261,195,270"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="4" class="notbutton" id="ch04_02" shape="poly" coords="202,283,215,275,214,279,223,280,234,280,245,277,257,271,265,264,273,253,278,241,280,233,296,235,290,257,283,269,276,276,267,285,251,292,235,297,220,297,210,295,209,298,202,283"   
  /> 

    <area  data-imgid="4" class="notbutton" id="ch04_01" shape="poly" coords="206,177,216,174,231,173,247,177,257,183,266,191,273,201,278,212,274,213,288,220,297,207,294,208,289,196,282,184,271,172,260,165,245,159,230,156,214,157,199,161,206,177"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="2" id="ch02" shape="poly" coords="214,234,216,246,228,241,238,246,240,233,248,227,239,219,237,207,226,212,216,208,215,219,205,227,214,234"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="3" id="ch03" shape="poly" coords="181,226,189,227,181,229,182,237,186,247,192,256,199,262,203,266,207,261,206,267,213,270,222,272,232,272,242,269,250,266,247,262,251,266,259,259,265,251,269,242,272,234,272,227,267,227,272,226,271,218,269,209,264,201,257,193,250,188,247,191,247,187,239,182,226,181,214,183,207,186,205,187,208,194,203,188,196,193,189,201,184,211,181,221,181,226"   
   /> 
 </map>

<div class="back side">
<img id="image1" src="blbl.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9;' usemap="#map2" />
</div>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="mi"></p>
<p id="clicked"></p>
<div id = "mapButtons" >
<button class = "prevButton" type="button"><img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/PjVnMY1.png"></button>
<button id="flip-button" class = "changeButton" type="button" onclick= "flip();switchVisible();"><img id="image" src="mapButton1.png"></button>
<button class = "nextButton" type="button"><img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/sR3xfJl.png"></button>
</div> 

<div id = "modelButtons" >
<button class = "prevButton" type="button"><img id="image" src="prevButton.png"></button>
<button id="flip-button" class = "changeButton" type="button" onclick= "flip(); switchVisible();"><img id="image" src="modelButton1.png"></button>
<button class = "nextButton" type="button" ><img id="image" src="nextButton.png"></button>
</div>

 <p id="d"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: The global variable var img_id = 2; is global variable, which when changed in click function of image, i want the change to stay when navigating through button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try tracking the current image using a variable:

```
var img = 1;
```

Then in the onClick functions, you can increment or decrement that variable & add your border class name to that image.

CSS: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/uj4uLoy6/)

```
img {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.myBorder {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/uj4uLoy6/)

```
<img id="1" class="myBorder"/>
<img id="2"/>
<img id="3"/>
<img id="4"/> 

<button class="prevButton">Prev</button>
<button class="nextButton">Next</button>
```

JS (requires jQuery): [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/uj4uLoy6/)

```
$(function() {
  var img = 1;
  var min = 1;
  var max = 4;

  $('.prevButton').on('click',function(e) {
    if (img > min) {
      img--;
      changeImage();
    }
  });

  $('.nextButton').on('click',function(e) {
    if (img < max) {
      img++;
      changeImage();
    }
  });

  $('img').on('click',function(e){
    img = $(this).attr('id');
    changeImage();
  });

  function changeImage() {
     $('img').removeClass('myBorder');  // Removes all Borders
     $('#' + img).addClass('myBorder'); // Applies Image Change
  }
});
```

Comment: If a person has clicked directly on image, then the navigation should start from that image. Example, if a person has clicked on img id=3, then next button should show image 04 and previous button should show image 02). If a person has not clike on any image the the navigation should start from 1,2,3,4 order for next).

Comment: Right now when i integrated your code. Which works perfectly well, but the navigation starts from starting image no matter what the user has cliked on previously.

Comment: i wanat var img = 1; to take value 1 only if click function on the image is not used, if that is used it shopuld take value of cliked function image.

Comment: I have made changes in the jsfiddle and integrated your code

Comment: Cool! I've edited the code to show how easy it is to use a changeImage function from both the next & previous buttons, as well as the image clicks. Image carousels are easy to build. I'm glad that it works for you! :)

Comment: the navigation always starts from the first image. I want the prev and next button arrows to work from the image which was clicked by the user.

Comment: There are two ways to navigate. One is by clicking the images, the second way is by prev and next button. If user first clicks on any random image ,and then uses prev and next button then the navigation should start from that numberic image id.

Comment: oops sorry, did not notice until now that you edited. Ia m going to try this code to integrate with mine and inform you if that works. thank youo for help.

Comment: works perfectly fine. Thank you soo much. I was stuck on this. I am going to mark this answer correct.